# debuggin jQuery ajax error on POST using firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, html-post

So I have an ajax call to submit my post without refresh, when I click on the submit button I tried to see what is the error on firebug console, however it goes off the screen very fast and I can't see what the error is. Any idea on what I do? I tried printing to the console and this is gone in a click as well.. I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Did you try checking "Persist" in the console?

Comment: Damn, yes it is on persist.. I can see it now.. However I am now clueless on debugging the error as all it says there is statusText error.. why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's not doing AJAX at all, but instead doing a normal request.  That can happen if you don't prevent the default action in your submit handler.  Try returning false from your submit handler (or button click handler, whatever triggers the form post).  If that doesn't work, try persisting the network requests in Firebug to see if the AJAX request is even being made.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your AJAX is failing and throwing an error, and the script just ends up navigating to the new page.

You could remove the `href` from the link (or `action` from the `form`) by setting it to `#`, and then pass the AJAX a string with what the link would have been.

I prefer just to click then spam the Esc key, it's far more fun :)